# How to make total after the count column values in SQL

Tags: sql

I try to find

```
select Code, count(Code) 
from Table 
group by code
```

and need result to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
SELECT Code, count(Code) as count
FROM Table 
GROUP BY count
```

You just need to adjust your GROUP BY condition.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do this somewhere other than in SQL, but it still works to have the total column. If you want to work on the ordering to make sure that the TOTAL column is at the bottom. Add an ortdering column and order by that

```
select Code, count(Code) 
from Table 
group by code
UNION
select 'All' as Code, count(Code) as COUNT
from Table
```